# Read a json file and visualizing with Google Chart API using Symfony2

Tags: php, json, symfony, twig

I have a JSON file containing some data. I want to read those file and visualize it with Google Chart API using Symfony2 framework.

I can do the same work using PHP by:

//getData.php

```
<?php 
 $string=file_get_contents("data.json");
 echo $string;
?>
```

and specify the url in HTML file as:

```
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization','1',{'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart);
    function drawchart(){
        var jsonData=$.ajax({
            url:"getData.php",
            datatype:"json",
            async:false
        }).responseText;
        var data=new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data,{width:400,height:240});
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**But I want to to same thing in symfony2. So how can i do this?**

Comment: create a function in site any controller `public function getjsodataAction(){  $string=file_get_contents("data.json");
 echo $string;die }` and call it at `ajax url:"http://localhost/projectname/controller/getjsodata"`

Comment: @JitendraYadav Close, but it could be done better. `getJsonDataAction()` should return `JsonResponse`